# CSS show div background over image element

Tags: css, background, gradient, overlap

I have this HTML: **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y2NLr/)**

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="image" src="someUrl">
    <div class="gradientDown"></div>
    <div class="gradientUp"></div>
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
.container {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding-top:70.5px;
}

.gradientDown {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(40,40,40,1), rgba(40,40,40,0));
}

.gradientUp {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:linear-gradient(to top, rgba(40,40,40,1), rgba(40,40,40,0));
}
```

I would like the gradient divs to overlap over the image, which is visibly hovering between them. I've tried tweaking around the z-indexes, positions, and displays, and I can't seem to find a way to do it. They always come out underneath the image.

Comment: Fiddle of what you have: http://jsfiddle.net/y2NLr/ .  Do you have an image of how it *should* look?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/butani_vijay010/xL7GR/ check it out it working fine

Comment: i do not understsand what u looking for.. maybe your browser not updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

****Now Define your*** `img` `z-index` **property** *

as like this

```
img{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;  
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k9f2a/1/)**

More about **[z-index](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)**

Answer (score 2):

z-index doesn't work on elements that have position:static (the default). If you give your img some positioning the z-index should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div{
            position:  relative;
        }
        .container {
            position:relative;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            padding-top:70.5px;
        }

        .gradientDown {
            position:relative;
            margin-top: -300px;
            top:0;
            width:100%;
            height:100px;
            background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(40,40,40,1), rgba(40,40,40,0));
        }

        .gradientUp {
            position: relative;
            bottom:0;
            width:100%;
            height:100px;
            background:linear-gradient(to top, rgba(40,40,40,1), rgba(40,40,40,0));
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div><img class="image" src="someurl"></div>
    <div class="gradientDown"></div>
    <div class="gradientUp"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```